# Windows 10 tablet mode Registry setting: Remember what I last used

Tags: registry, tablet, windows-10, registrykey

I already have the registry key to disable tablet mode, but if I restart it puts it back into tablet mode unless I change "sign in" to "Remember what I last used". Here is a picture of what I am talking about.

http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/ah134/fac7orx2/tablet%20mode%20last%20used22_zpsinqpghnl.png

I need to do this for an installer, so I want to change the registry key for "sign in" to "Remember what I last used". Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for the answer too

Answer (score 2):

Tablet mode settings are found in the registry under `[HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell]`

The two important keys for you are TabletMode and SignInMode (you may have to create them).

TabletMode:

```
0 = Off
1 = On
```

SignInMode:

```
0 = "Automatically switch to Tablet Mode"
1 = "Go to the desktop"
2 = "Remember what I used last"
```

Comment: I have created/modified these two keys, but everytime I restart Windows Explorer, TablemMode is reset to 0. Any idea what might be causing it and how to resolve this issue?